# Find matching Enums in a Vector and return an error in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm always willing to find the best solution, with the best performance in my software.
So, I would like to ask if there's a best option to solve my problem.

I have a defined Enum

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Hash, PartialOrd, Ord, ::prost::Enumeration)]
#[repr(i32)]
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
#[derive(strum_macros::EnumString, strum_macros::Display)]
pub enum CarMotive {
    Standard = 0,
    Deluxe = 1,
    Sport = 2,
}
```

And I have a Vector of Strings `["standard","deluxe"]`, that is comming from a csv file.
I would like to check the coincidences between the Vector and the Enums.
In case there's no "match" give an error for each Enum option.

I solved it that way.
I have a function for each Enum Option, and in case there's no match I have a function that returns an error.

Motive 1:

```
pub fn find_standard(
    dataset: &[String],
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match dataset.iter().find(|&m| {
        let car_motive = CarMotive::from_str(&m.motive);
        if car_motive == Ok(CarMotive::Standard) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }) {
        Some(_x) => (),
        None => print_an_error(&format!(
            "CarMotive:Standard Motive missing in vector"
        )),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Motive 2:

```
pub fn find_deluxe(
    dataset: &[String],
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match dataset.iter().find(|&m| {
        let car_motive = CarMotive::from_str(&m.motive);
        if car_motive == Ok(CarMotive::Deluxe) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }) {
        Some(_x) => (),
        None => print_an_error(&format!(
            "CarMotive:Deluxe Motive missing in vector"
        )),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Motive 3:

```
pub fn find_sport(
    dataset: &[String],
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    match dataset.iter().find(|&m| {
        let car_motive = CarMotive::from_str(&m.motive);
        if car_motive == Ok(CarMotive::Sport) {
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }) {
        Some(_x) => (),
        None => print_an_error(&format!(
            "CarMotive:Sport Motive missing in vector"
        )),
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

And the way that I have to test it:

```
#[test]
#[serial]
fn find_standard_nok() {
    let dataset = vec!["deluxe".to_string()];

    let mut s_err = String::new();
    {
        let mut err_ssh = shh::stderr().unwrap();
        find_standard(&dataset).unwrap();
        let _ = err_ssh.read_to_string(&mut s_err).unwrap();
    }
    assert_eq!(s_err, "\"CarMotive:Standard Motive missing in vector\"\n");
}
```

I think it doesn't have the best performance, 'cause it's "looping" the dataset 3 times.
In case the Enum grows, I have to add another function to check for the match as well.

I have a Frontend background and it's sometimes hard for me to solve functions like that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understant what you're saying by "it's looping the dataset 3 times". Your `find` functions traverse the entire input because they're trying to find *if* the input has the variant (incidentally it doesn't really make any sense that they return anything other than non-booleans to me), but if you just want to traverse the dataset once you can… just map `CarMotive::from_str` over the input then find what you need on the result using scan or find or fold?

Comment: Incidentally aside from the return types I find deeply unsuitable your code is a bit odd e.g. `if car_motive == Ok(CarMotive::Standard) { true } else { false }` is just `car_motive == Ok(CarMotive::Standard)`.

Comment: Also you could pass in the variant you're looking for to your finder instead of coding the same function 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get something like what you're asking for, and also de-deuplicate your functions, is to run through your data and keep track of the unique `enum` values you've seen, like so:

```
pub fn find_matches(dataset: &[String]) -> HashSet<CarMotive> {
    let mut matches = HashSet::new();
    dataset.iter().for_each(|m| {
        if let Ok(car_motive) = CarMotive::from_str(&m) {
            matches.insert(car_motive);
        }
    });

    return matches;
}
```